# converting equation from vector to matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an equation to calculate the values of a $3\times 1$ vector from another vector:

$$ \left( {\begin{array}{c}y\\c_b\\c_r\\\end{array} } \right) = 
   \left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\a_4 & a_5 & a_6\\a_7 & a_8 & a_9\\\end{array} } \right)\cdot
   \left( {\begin{array}{c}r\\g\\b\\\end{array}} \right) $$

where $a_i$ are some constant values which are not important for the question.

This is all good and well for 1 set of $r,g,b$ values, but I have many values, of $r,g,b$ arrange in matrices, one for the values of $r$, one for $g$ and one for $b$. Is there a way to calculate the appropriate matrices for the values of $y$, $c_b$ and $c_r$ without calculation the value of each set individually but instead using matrix operations for one (or three) big calculation(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I got it right, you have vectors $\mathbf{r}^{(i)}=[r^{(i)},g^{(i)},b^{(i)}]^T$, the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, and want to compute vectors $\mathbf{y}^{(i)}=[y^{(i)},c_b^{(i)},c_r^{(i)}]^T=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}^{(i)}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, where $n$ is some large number.

If you define matrices $\mathbf{R}=[\mathbf{r}^{(1)},\ldots,\mathbf{r}^{(n)}]$ and $\mathbf{Y}=[\mathbf{y}^{(1)},\ldots,\mathbf{y}^{(n)}]$, you have $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}$.

There are some [specialised algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) for computing matrix-matrix products, but most of them are designed for (larger) square matrices. Otherwise, the matrix-matrix product consists of three nested loops which can be organised in any way to get an efficient implementation with respect to the storage schemes used.

Assuming that $\mathbf{A}$ is stored as a 9-element array (so that it's likely to be stored permanently in the cache), it really depends on how is your organisation of the "vector" data.

You can naively simply compute $\mathbf{y}^{(i)}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}^{(i)}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, that is, compute $\mathbf{Y}$ column by column, which will probably work the best if you have the vectors stored as an $n$-array of real triplets.

If you have the vectors stored in three long (contiguous) arrays, you might consider the row-wise version.
Since $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}$, we have $\mathbf{e}_i^T\mathbf{Y}=(\mathbf{e}_i^T\mathbf{A})\mathbf{R}$ (where $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the $i$th column of the $3\times 3$ identity matrix); $\mathbf{e}_i^T\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{e}_i^T\mathbf{A}$ hence represents the $i$th row of $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{A}$. It means that the $i$th row ($i=1,2,3$) of $\mathbf{Y}$ is given by the linear combination of the rows of $\mathbf{R}$ with the coefficients given by the $i$th row of $\mathbf{A}$. So the row-wise approach will lead to the outer loop of the length $3$ instead of $n$ (in the case of the column-wise approach). However, if the vectors are stored as triplets, this will probably be less efficient than the column-wise variant due to the increased number of cache misses.